# Will the transferred manuscript at the new journal (B) be sent back to the same reviewers at the transferring journal (A)?

Tags: publications, peer-review

I submitted a manuscript to Journal A. After review, 2 reviewers were positively endorsed for publication. However, 1 reviewer and editor suggests publishing it in another journal (B) in the same system. So We agreed, revised, and transferred to Journal B. So my question is:
Will the transferred manuscript at the new journal (B) be sent back to the same reviewers at the transferring journal (A)? or they will invite a fresh new set of reviewers?

Thanks

Note: Journal A is higher than B in ranking, same system.

Comment: We can't answer this. It depends on whether the reviewers have agreed that their information can be transferred, on editorial policies and, as always, on the handling editor's decision.

Comment: Could anyone with editorial experience/handling this kind of transfer manuscript answer this question? Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is any useful general answer.  I think it would be quite normal to *consider* inviting the same reviewers (unless the journal has a policy against it). However, there are many reasons an editor might decide not to do so. In particular, if the target readership of the new journal is different from the first, there may be an argument for getting reviewers from this community. Also, if the original reviews were positive the editor may feel that further reviews from those people would not provide additional useful information. Everything depends on the circumstances.

Comment: It is what it is. You will get a decision eventually. How they reach it is up to them.

Comment: It's even imaginable that the editor for B will accept the paper without further review. There were two positive reviews for A, and a third review that apparently found the paper suitable for B.  Maybe the two positive reviewers found the paper good for A  but specifically not for B, but if that's not the case, the B editor could conclude that there's already enough positive information to accept the paper.

Comment: It could also happen that the referees of A serve for B as well. In that case, depending also on the contact among editors as well your accompanying letter (if any), the whole procedure at B can be shortened and have a positive outcome.

Answer (score 3):

I would expect that where the editor suggests "transferring" to a specific journal, it is because there is some arrangement that this can be done while keeping the same reviewers (assuming that they are happy for this to happen, but I don't see why they would object). Unless the new version of the paper has significant differences, the next review should be relatively quick. This has happened to me.

It is of course not uncommon for reviewers, if they don't think the paper is strong enough for the current journal, to suggest a specific other journal which would be suitable, and you shouldn't read anything into that (other than "if I were reviewing for journal B, I would recommend acceptance). But if the editor endorses that suggestion, and particularly if they use the word "transfer" rather than "resubmit", it suggests they think they can expedite the process for journal B.

Answer (score 0):

**Probably not** - because the new journal B does not know which reviewers were invited by A. This information, as well as the reviews received by journal A, is not usually shared between journals.

The manuscript could still be sent to the same reviewers, but that would mean the editors of A and B independently agreed that [reviewer] is an expert on the topic who can review the paper.

Comment: "not usually shared between journals" That's just incorrect if the journals belong to the same publisher. It is increasingly common that reviewers are asked when they submit a review if they consent to their review being transferred if the manuscript is transferred to another journal.